# Rsync and clone of server

Tags: mariadb, rsync

Has anyone here ever determined a fairly easy way to configure a clone of their Centos 7 server such that both the public_html files and one database can stay in sync with another server?  Rsync can handle the files, and I could script the database tables I need to maintain via a scripting file which runs via a cron job a few times a day.  Has anyone ever found or created instructions for something like this?  This would be a way for me to create load balancing for some of my web sites when they are behind a proxy server which already provides an easy way to load balance across a multiplicity of servers.  I have already done a clone of my server and have it running.  I just want to reduce the ongoing time needed to maintain it when files are added to public_html and database changes are made.  Could I perhaps just use Git and store the database there as well?

Answer (score 0):

For the basic sync:
How about:
Make an ansible playbook out of the steps required, then trigger it via cron

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/synchronize_module.html.

Alternatively, if on the same network/site create an nfs export and mount it on the other server. May hit issues with file locks for write access, depending really on the load balancer and app configuration (not applicable if one of the systems is set as read only).

Comment: Thanks so much, I am going to work on going that way.  Jim